# Returning a URL string of an API endpoint

Tags: java, android, url

I have a class with multiple methods which return a URL string of an API endpoint. Each method takes different parameters based on what the endpoint have to include.

Examples (among others):

1. **GET**: `http://api.mydomain.com/v1/shopping_lists/items/categories`
2. **GET**: `http://api.mydomain.com/v1/shopping_lists/items?last_sync_date=2016-09-29T17%3A14%3A51Z&page_number=1&page_limit=10&include=categories%2Csubcategories`
3. **POST**: `http://api.mydomain.com/v1/users/{user_guid}/shopping_lists/{shopping_list_guid}/items`
4. **GET**: `http://api.mydomain.com/v1/users/guid?include=devices%2Cshopping_lists.items.images%2Cshopping_lists.occasions`

As we can see in the URLs, I have query parameters as well as the HTTP method in which the API is getting, along with the body request in JSON or form-data.

---

This is my current approach on building those URL strings:

I'm using OkHttp as the HTTP client. Firstly, I've created an abstract class called `BaseHttpCall`. Inside, I put all of the HTTP methods with the Request Builder like so:

```
public abstract class BaseHttpCall {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.mydomain.com";
    private static final String VER = "/v1/";
    private static final String API_URL = BASE_URL + VER;

    public Request post(String endpoint, RequestBody requestBody, boolean auth) {
        return new Request.Builder()
                .url(API_URL + endpoint)
                .post(requestBody)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .addHeader("Authorization", (auth) ? "Bearer " + session.token().get() : "")
                .build();
    }

    public Request get(String endpoint, boolean auth) {
        return new Request.Builder()
                .url(API_URL + endpoint)
                .get()
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .addHeader("Authorization", (auth) ? "Bearer " + session.token().get() : "")
                .build();
    }

    // other HTTP method builder ...

    public String buildQueryString(String endpoint, HashMap<String, String> keyValuePair) throws APIError {

        // process keyValuePair

        return mEndpointWithQueryString;
    }
}
```

For the endpoint management, I put it in a class called `Endpoints` that holds all of the endpoints:

```
public class Endpoints {

    public static final String DEVICES = "devices";
    public static final String USERS = "users";
    public static final String SHOPPING_LIST = "shopping_lists";
    public static final String SMS = "sms";
    // ... other endpoints


    /**
     * Build Shopping List endpoint for Create/View
     */
    public static String buildShoppingListEndpoint(String user_guid, String[] includes) {
        String mBaseEndpoint =
                USERS + "/" + user_guid + "/" +
                        SHOPPING_LIST;
        if (includes == null) {
            return mBaseEndpoint;
        }
        return mBaseEndpoint + include(includes);
    }

    /**
     * Build Shopping List endpoint for Update/Delete
     */
    public static String buildShoppingListEndpoint(String user_guid, String shopping_list_guid, String[] includes) {
        String mBaseEndpoint =
                USERS + "/" + user_guid + "/" +
                        SHOPPING_LIST + "/" + shopping_list_guid;
        if (includes == null) {
            return mBaseEndpoint;
        }
        return mBaseEndpoint + include(includes);
    }

    /**
     * Build User Shopping List Item endpoint
     *
     */
    public static String buildGroceryListEndpoint(String user_guid, String shopping_list_guid, String item_guid, String[] includes) {
        String mBaseEndpoint =
                USERS + "/" + user_guid + "/" +
                        SHOPPING_LIST + "/" + shopping_list_guid + "/" +
                        ITEMS + (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(item_guid) ? "/" + item_guid : "");
        if (includes == null) {
            return mBaseEndpoint;
        }
        return mBaseEndpoint + include(includes);
    }

    // ... other build methods

    /**
     * Construct the query parameter for requesting custom response
     */
    private static String include(String[] includes) {
        return "?include=" + StringUtils.join(includes, ",");
    }

    private static String slash() {
        return "/";
    }
}
```

In order to use these functions, I would do this - example for building Sub Category Item Endpoint (considering this function is inside a class which extends `BaseHttpCall` abstract method):

```
String[] includes = {"category", "items"};
HashMap<String, String> keyValuePair = new HashMap<>();
// ... key value pair builder here

Request request = 
    get(
        buildQueryString(
            Endpoints.buildSubCategoryItemEndpoint(user_guid, sub_category_id, null), keyValuePair), true);
```

I think this smells terrible behind the scenes. Are there any improvements I can do to make this more readable and maintainable in the backend, along with making the usage of the Endpoint builder more easily?

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would get rid of the `Endpoints` class. You can encapsulate the individual endpoint configurations/formats in an inheritance hierarchy. This has the added benefit of not being publicly exposed should anything with the API change.

Secondly (and this is only a small thing) I would rename `BaseHttpCall` to something like `MyApiRequest`. If your domain name is let's say dutchcourage.com, then I would call the class `DutchCourageApiRequest`.

Here is the code implementing my suggested changes:

```
public abstract class DutchCourageApiRequest {

  private static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.dutchcourage.com";
  private static final String VER = "/v1/";
  private static final String API_URL = BASE_URL + VER;

  public abstract Request post(RequestBody requestBody, boolean auth);

  public abstract Request get(boolean auth);

  protected Request post(String endpoint, RequestBody requestBody, boolean auth) {
    return new Request.Builder()
        .url(API_URL + endpoint)
        .post(requestBody)
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .addHeader("Authorization", (auth) ? "Bearer " + session.token().get() : "")
        .build();
  }

  protected Request get(String endpoint, boolean auth) {
    return new Request.Builder()
        .url(API_URL + endpoint)
        .get()
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .addHeader("Authorization", (auth) ? "Bearer " + session.token().get() : "")
        .build();
  }

  // other HTTP method builder ...

  protected String buildQueryString(String endpoint, HashMap<String, String> keyValuePair) throws APIError {
    String mEndpointWithQueryString = null;
    // process keyValuePair
    return mEndpointWithQueryString;
  }

}
```

The sub category item concrete implementation.

```
public class SubCategoryItemApiRequest extends DutchCourageApiRequest {

  @Override
  public Request post(RequestBody requestBody, boolean auth) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public Request get(boolean auth) {
    String[] includes = {"category", "items"};
    Map<String, String> keyValuePair = new HashMap<>();
    // ... key value pair builder here

    Request request =
        get(
            buildQueryString(
                buildSubCategoryItemEndpoint(user_guid, sub_category_id, null), keyValuePair), true);
  }

  private String buildSubCategoryItemEndpoint(String user_guid, String sub_category_id, String other) {
    // create url string
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should remove all comments, since they only repeat what the method names say already.

You should remove the `slash` method since it is not used. And it should not be.

Instead of using string concatenation, you could use string formatting (only if you find it easier to read):

```
String url1 = "/" + user + "/" + guid + includes(includes);

Steing url2 = String.format("/%s/%s%s", user, guid, includes(includes));
```

The `includes` method should handle a `null` or empty array. This avoids code duplication in the code that calls this method.